# How to thread safe a complex data object?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here is my data object that I want to make thread safe:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<ClassA, ClassB>>
```

Here are the definitions of the Classes, without the hashcode defs:

```
public ClassA{
   public string String1 {get; set;}
   public string String2 {get; set;}
}

public ClassB{
   public double Double1 {get; set;}
   public double Double2 {get; set;}
}
```

Basically the nested dictionary structure values are constantly changing. I want to thread this object out to be then sent/published to a Message Queue (RabbitMQ). I'm running into Exceptions being thrown where it says the Enum collection is being changed as it is sent/published to the MQ.

How can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your question is quite vague as we can't really see how you are using your dictionary. But sounds like it may help if you create a snapshot copy of your data and send that to the queue.

Comment: Unless we are able to understand exactly how you intend to use your Dictionary of Dictionaries and whether instances of ClassA and ClassB are going to be simultaneously manipulated from different threads, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: You guys are correct - I created a copy of my object and just threaded that instead. Many thanks!

Comment: If you're using `ClassA` as a dictionary key you must make sure that you override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` properly. Which also means making it an immutable class.

Answer (score 0):

All the values being put into the nested Dictionary happens on the same thread.

I created a copy of that object into a new data object and threaded that instead, it works like a charm.